# 2D Array with malloc() error

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic, malloc, 2d

I am trying to dynamically allocate an array in c based on the command line arguments, but I am getting an exception error. What am I doing wrong?

```
int **array =(int**)malloc(Argument1);
for(a=0;a<Argument2;a++)
    array[a]=(int*)malloc(Argument2);
```

and the exeption is thrown after:

```
__forceinline void * __cdecl _heap_alloc (size_t size)
{ 
 //stuff here
 return HeapAlloc(_crtheap, 0, size ? size : 1); }
```

I got past the for loop once and then got an access error when trying to read the data, but every other time it triggers a breakpoint. What could I be doing wrong in Visual Studio?

Comment: Those mallocs cannot possibly be correct.  Firstly, do not cast the return of malloc in C. Secondly, in your loop, you are progressively allocating more and more memory. First time, 1 byte. Next time 2 bytes (for a total of 3), next time three bytes, etc., until you reach the value of Argument 2.

Comment: You are right, they are not correct but I am struggling to figure out why they aren't working

Comment: You don't show the code that is doing the access, yet you say, "...got an access error when trying to read the data..."

Comment: I'm guessing that should be `array[a]=..` instead of `array[i]`, unless `i` is initialized and updated in code you did not post.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the `malloc` function is the size in bytes, not in number of elements, because there is no way for malloc to know each element's size.
Also the loop should loop through Argument1, not Argument2.

Try this:

```
int **array = malloc(arg1 * sizeof(int*));
for (int I = 0; I < arg1; I++) {
    array[I] = malloc(arg2 * sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: I get an error: "a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int **"

Comment: Also, VS says "type is not allowed" on the (arg2 * int) part

Comment: @luvAtime41 Per the 1st, I bet you are compile the code as C++, not C, because malloc in C returns a void *, aka the general pointer, you should not cast it. For the 2nd, sorry it was my fault, I should typed sizeof(int) there. :)

Comment: @luvAtime41 I suggest you change the file extention to ".c" and try again.

Comment: Is there another setting to change in VS? The file extension is .c

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure about VS, but the errors you showed clearly indicates that the code was not compiled as C but C++.

Comment: @luvAtime41 "*To force the compiler to treat all files as C regardless of file name extension, use the /Tc compiler option.*" (from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838.aspx)